# Mapbox Navigation SDK integration with SwiftUI 5

Tags: ios, navigation, mapbox

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox
import MapboxAnnotationExtension
import MapboxDirections
import MapboxCoreNavigation
import MapboxNavigation

/****** some classes for different types of annotations

struct MapboxRepresent: UIViewRepresentable {

................

   class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
            let navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: directionsRoute!)
            navigationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            !!!! -> present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
// here is error - Use of unresolved identifier 'present'
        }
   }

.................

}
```

This code works properly; it shows map and all annotations. 
The function for tap is just for testing. As I'm new in SwiftUI5 I can not understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: `present` is a `UiViewController` method. Your object called `Coordinator` inherits from `NSObject` and `MGLMapViewDelegate` but not `UIViewController` Hence the unresolved identifier. It has no idea what the `present` method is because it really shouldn’t.

Comment: I know. Problem is I can not understand in which place I have to activate navigation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call .present inside a Coordinator defined in SwiftUI View. You need to create a new SwiftUI View that represents the Mapbox NavigationViewController. Then you can use .sheet to open a modal for that Swift navigation view. Look at this [tutorial](https://justwrite.link/posts/cpPcKRz7naPZZFvb8kNX) to know how to bring a Mapbox map and navigation to iOS app using SwiftUI.